# How to easily find patch target in unittest?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, python-mock

I have the following module structure within a Django app:

```
subscriptions
   - api
     - views.py
     - serializers.py
     - tests
       test_some_view.py

   - models.py
   - signals.py
```

In `models.py` I have a `GooglePlayOrder` model, and in `signals.py` I have a signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=GooglePlayOrder)
def save_google_play_order(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   pass
```

The `GooglePlayOrder` instance is being created in a serializer `GooglePlayOrderSerializer` from `api/serializers.py`, which is called by some `GooglePlayOrderView` in `api/views.py`.

And now I want to run a test from `api/tests/test_some_view.py`, where I want to mock the `save_google_play_order` signal.

Unfortunately, this implementation does not work, as I (AFAIK) should follow the imports for patching something:

```
@patch('subscriptions.signals.save_google_play_order')
def test_normal(self, mock):
```

So, how should I understand in this case what exactly I should use as a target of `patch` decorator?

Answer (score 1):

Try where the mocked function is used. For example, if you use `save_google_play_order` in `serializers.py`:

`@patch('subscriptions.api.serializers.save_google_play_order')`